# React native: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.props.passwordChanged(text)')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I defined the following actions in `../actions/AuthActions.js`:

```
export const emailChanged = (text) => {..};
export const passwordChanged = (text) => {..};
```

and exported them in "./index.js" as

```
export * from './AuthActions';
```

Imported the actions in LoginForm.js with

```
import { passwordChanged, emailChanged } from '../actions';
```

and used the actions in the following way:

```
onEmailChange(text) {
   this.props.emailChanged(text);
}

onPasswordChange(text) {
    this.props.passwordChanged(text);
}
```

On running the code in the emulator, I get the error 'undefined is not a function...', even though I have defined the function, exported the name. One of the exported names 'emailChanged' works as expected but only that one and as far as I can see there is nothing special about that name. I know I must be missing something glaringly obvious, but would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using redux, and trying to call actions from your component. The problem is that you did not connect your action creators with to component with redux's connect Higher Order Component.

What you need to do, is add these actions with connect like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { emailChanged, passwordChanged })(LoginScreen)
```

This way, those actions will be available in this.props.

Comment: Thank you!, I had done that for emailChanged but not for passwordChanged! :)